# Middle button (mouse wheel) not working: no new tab, no past of marked text in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, mouse

**Windows 10**

When working with Windows I am used to open a new browser (chrome, Firefox) with the middle mouse button. 
Unfortunately with the Logitech G602 it is no working :(

**Ubuntu 16.04**

In Ubuntu I have the same issue using the Logitech G602 : Mouse wheel does not work as middle button:

- Mouse wheel / middle button does not open a new browser tab
- Mouse wheel / middle button does not paste a text previously marked

To me it looks like a driver or settings issue.
**How can I fix it?**
(If I remember right I had the same issue under windows as soon as I installed the logitec driver)

Comment: Please open a terminal, run `xev` within the terminal, middle click *once* (try to not move the mouse more than absolutely necessary), then hit Ctrl+C to exit xev. Then copy the xev output into your question.

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu: Using `xev` on the command line I realized that two of the buttons did not result in any output. So I assume they are not working any more :/

One of the buttons not working any more is the middle key.

Comment: Install `evtest` and identify which input event is triggered by your mouse. Then do `cat /dev/input/eventXX` and use the button. You'll see whether this device actually sends the click information or not (to rule out any physical damage). Mine shows something in `/dev/input/event` but nothing on xev. So I think it's a software defect.